# Unable to plot data json data on highcharts

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

I am trying to load json data to high-charts. I am receiving json data from DB using $.getJSON function. Here is my sample json that i am receiving from DB,

My sample json

[
{
"target":"collectd.matrix.oracle.avg_resp_time","datapoints":[[8.0, 1365158480],[null, 1365158490],[null, 1365158500],[null, 1365158510],[null, 1365158520],[null,1365158530],[8.0, 1365158540],[null, 1365158550],[null, 1365158560],[null, 1365158570],[null, 1365158580],[null, 1365158590]]
}
]

$.getJSON("myURL", createOrderDurationChart);
On success response from $.getJSON i call function below,
I am using  scala framework.
I am not getting what is wrong in code or json. I can plot this json by embedding code in simple javascript and run through html directly as sample.

Here is the sample code,

```
function createOrderDurationChart(durationMap){
//var target=durationMap[0].target;
//var jsonstr=durationMap[0].datapoints;
//alert(target);
//alert(jsonstr);
var orderDurationChart = new Highcharts.Chart({
chart: {
renderTo: "order_duration_div",
type: "column",
margin: [10, null, null, null],                          
//marginRight: 10,
zoomType: 'xy',
},
title: {
text: "order duration"
//y: 5  
},
xAxis: {
type: "datetime",
//tickInterval: 60*1000*10
},
yAxis: {
title: {
text: "seconds"
},
startOnTick : false,
endOnTick: false
},
series: [{
name:"avg",
data: (function (){
var data = [], i;
var jsondata = [];
jsondata= durationMap[0].datapoints;
alert(jsondata)
var datapoints=JSON.parse(jsondata);
// var jsonstr=parsejson[0].datapoints;
console.log('jsotn ' + datapoints);
// var mydata = JSON.parse(jsonstr);
// alert(mydata);
//  datapoints = mydata[0].datapoints;
//alert("initial:" + json[0].time + ':' + json[0].value);
for (i = 0; i < datapoints.length; i++) {
data.push({
x:datapoints[i][1],
y:datapoints[i][0]
});
console.log('x: ' + datapoints[i][1] + ', y: ' + datapoints[i][0]);
}
return data;
})
()}]
});
}
```

Update code after json fix,

```
function createOrderDurationChart(durationMap){
//var target=durationMap[0].target;
//var jsonstr=durationMap[0].datapoints;
//alert(target);
//alert(jsonstr);
var orderDurationChart = new Highcharts.Chart({
chart: {
renderTo: "order_duration_div",
type: "column",
margin: [10, null, null, null],                          
//marginRight: 10,
zoomType: 'xy',
},
title: {
text: "order duration"
//y: 5  
},
xAxis: {
type: "datetime",
//tickInterval: 60*1000*10
},
yAxis: {
title: {
text: "seconds"
},
startOnTick : false,
endOnTick: false
},
series: [{
name:"avg",
data: (function (){
var data = [], i;
var jsondata = [];
datapoints= durationMap[0].datapoints;    
console.log('jsotn ' + datapoints);      
for (i = 0; i < datapoints.length; i++) {
data.push({
x:datapoints[i][1],
y:datapoints[i][0]
});
console.log('x: ' + datapoints[i][1] + ', y: ' + datapoints[i][0]);
}
return data;
})
()}]
});
}
```

Any suggestions most welcome.
Thanks

Comment: I have resolved the issues of syntax error of json,i can see json data on console but still when data.push is done chart is not drawn.

Comment: If you have more points than 1000, set `turboThreshold` for series or change format from { x: x, y:y } to [x ,y]. Also, make sure that you are creating chart after JSON arrives.

Comment: I did not get exactly what you meant to say, can you please elaborate more with short example

Comment: Change this: `data.push({
x:datapoints[i][1],
y:datapoints[i][0]
});` to this: `data.push([
datapoints[i][1],
datapoints[i][0]
]);`

Comment: I tired but no luck,can you have look at my code please or suggest me different approach if posible for you.

Comment: So, as my second thought, set [turboThreshold](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.turboThreshold) to higher value. If this won't help you - do you have the latest (3.0.1) version of Highcharts? Also, recreate issue on jsFiddle, please (with fake data even).

Comment: Well  turboThreshold didnt work and yes i have older version of highcharts may e i can test again by having downloading latest version. Thanks

Comment: Yep it will be great. It will be easier to find bug in code by implementing it.Have you tested on old version this code?